# Next 13 Route Handler having issues getting data from body (app/api/auth)

Tags: javascript, typescript, routes, next.js

When I try to get the body out of the new  `export async function POST( req: Request)` I am getting it as a stream instead of the content type.
Here is the route handler located in `api/auth/signup`
[Folder layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04fYn.png)

```
export async function POST( req: NextRequest ) {
    //Send success response
    console.log( req.body );
    return new Response( req.body, {
        status: 200,
    });
}
```

The handler im sending it from is here

```
function handleSubmit( event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //form validation code here
    console.log( "Sent the request to the server" );
    fetch( "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup", {
       method : "POST",
       headers:{
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
       body: JSON.stringify({
           username: username,
           password: password,
           email   : email,
       }),
       next: { revalidate: 0 },
    })
    .then( res => res.json())
    .then( data => console.log( data.username, data.password, data.email ));
    
}
```

The end of this handler is able to print out the values ive sent to server, but trying to access them on the server's req.body is giving me a readable stream which obviously doesnt have the properties on it.
[Readable stream from body image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWBYp.png)

The app folder is experimental, but having a hard time seeing a simple feature just not work. Feel like this is a me problem (99.9% of programming :D)

This is all running through http / localhost if that could cause issues.

Ive tried looking for solutions but it seems like there are only other people having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the request into json format

```
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { user_id } = await request.json()
  console.log(user_id)

  return new Response('Success');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. Looks like they removed the auto-parsing from the content type for route handlers.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me a headache!

Comment: Ok, but what if I wanted to keep the `req: NextRequest` type?

Comment: @DiegoBenetti with app routing at the moment you can't keep that, it won't work.

Comment: you are right @DiegoBenetti did you find any way around

Comment: Yes, it's pretty simple, actually. You can declare the function like this: `export async function POST (request: NextRequest) {...}` and you get the body with `const body = await request.json();`.